# Best way to filter out duplicate stringified arithmetic operations in python list?

Tags: python

I have the following list: `['2*3=6', '3*2=6', '1+10/2=6.0', '2/1*3=6', '2*3/1=6', '3/1*2=6', '3*2/1=6', '10/2+1=6']`

I want to filter out equations that are equivalent in the numbers used. With this I mean I want to obtain a list of equations that only contain unique combinations of numbers. Such as: 2*3 or 3*2, 1+10/2=6.0 or 10/2+1=6.0 etc. I also want to print out what numbers weren't used in the calculation such as: (3*2=6 not used: 1 and 10) etc.

Haven't been able how to write a function that does this because I can't see what we would need to compare. I'd like this function to work for 1 to 9. So, 1 gives us the list: `['2-1=1', '3-2=1', '1*3-2=1', '3-1*2=1', '3*1-2=1', '3/1-2=1', '3-2*1=1', '3-2/1=1']` I want to filter this in the same way. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I want to filter out equations that are equivalent in the numbers used."

Comment: @tituszban I added it to the question. Is this better?

Comment: Yes. Couple more things. What's up with the usage of `6.0` vs `6`? Also, in the first two items I think you're missing two `'`s.

Comment: @tituszban The 6.0 vs 6 is caused by division I think I can use int() to just get 6. I'll fix the ```'```s

Comment: Given that this is mostly string processing, using integers consistently would be really useful.

Comment: What is your desired output for `['2*3=6', '3*2=6', '1+10/2=6.0', '2/1*3=6.0', '2*3/1=6.0', '3/1*2=6.0', '3*2/1=6.0', '10/2+1=6.0']`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 For example: ```['2*3=6', '2/1*3=6', '10/2+1=6']``` Or also valid: ```[ '3*2=6',  '3/1*2=6', '10/2+1=6']```

Comment: You will have to write a parser and build an AST that you can then inspect.

Comment: I am sure you asked today a question about itertools to generate such strings, right?

Comment: @sanyash That's right! I wasn't sure the question was logical though. And I have been able to generate the strings but I need to get rid of the 'duplicates'

Comment: So, it is not a good idea to generate such strings and then filter them. It is better to generate the strings in clever way, so they are all unique and don't need filtering.

Comment: @sanyash I think that's the answer yes.

Comment: @sanyash can you guide me in the right direction how I should use itertools to accomplish this? I used permutation but that can't be a right usage then.

Comment: You can edit and undelete your previous question. I will look on it and try to help you.

Comment: @sanyash undeleted thank you for your time! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078750/applying-arithmetic-operations-on-list-of-numbers-without-repetition-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pretty strait forward way of doing it:

```
import re

eqs =  ['2*3=6', '3*2=6', '1+10/2=6', '2/1*3=6', '2*3/1=6', '3/1*2=6', '3*2/1=6', '10/2+1=6']

by_digits_used = {}

remaining_digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for eq in eqs:
    used_digits = [int(f) for f in re.findall(r'\d*', eq) if f != ""]  # Find all digits in the equations
    used_digits.sort()                                                 # Ensure they're always in the same order
    used_digits = tuple(used_digits)                                   # Convert to tuple

    # Remove digits that were used
    for digit in used_digits:
        if digit in remaining_digits:
            remaining_digits.remove(digit)

    # Store equation by the digits used
    by_digits_used[used_digits] = by_digits_used.get(used_digits, []) + [eq]

print(by_digits_used)
print(remaining_digits)
```

Result:

```
# Equations by digits used
{(2, 3, 6): ['2*3=6', '3*2=6'], (1, 2, 6, 10): ['1+10/2=6', '10/2+1=6'], (1, 2, 3, 6): ['2/1*3=6', '2*3/1=6', '3/1*2=6', '3*2/1=6']}
# Unused digits
{0, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dictionary and set to do it like below

```py
import re
from itertools import chain

ls = ['2*3=6', '3*2=6', '1+10/2=6.0', '2/1*3=6', '2*3/1=6', '3/1*2=6', '3*2/1=6', '10/2+1=6']

exp = '10/2+1=6'

sorted_nums = [sorted([nums for nums  in re.findall("(\d+)", exp )]) for exp in ls]

unused_nums = set(map(str, range(1,10)))-set(chain(*sorted_nums))

nums_in_exps = {}
for nums, exp in zip(sorted_nums, ls):
    key = "-".join(nums)
    if key not in nums_in_exps:
        nums_in_exps[key] = []

    nums_in_exps[key] += [exp]

print("expression with nums")
print(nums_in_exps)

print("unused numbers")
print(unused_nums)
```

**output**

```
expression with nums
{'2-3-6': ['2*3=6', '3*2=6'], '0-1-10-2-6': ['1+10/2=6.0'], '1-2-3-6': ['2/1*3=6', '2*3/1=6', '3/1*2=6', '3*2/1=6'], '1-10-2-6': ['10/2+1=6']}
unused numbers
{'8', '4', '9', '7', '5'}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option using [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)

```
import re
import string

s = ['2*3=6', '3*2=6', '1+10/2=6.0', '2/1*3=6', '2*3/1=6', '3/1*2=6', '3*2/1=6', '10/2+1=6']
s = [i.replace('.0', '') for i in s]  # remove floats

d = {frozenset(re.split('[\+\-\*\/=]', i)): i for i in s}
print('Unique equations: ' , *d.values())
print('Unused numbers: ', set(string.digits) - frozenset.union(*d.keys()))
```

prints

```
Unique equations:  3*2=6 10/2+1=6 3*2/1=6
Unused numbers:  {'4', '0', '5', '9', '7', '8'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple syntax tree of groups which store the order of operations, and then you can traverse the tree with a new input object and attempt to find any group matches:

```
import re
def to_tree(d):
   if len(d) == 1:
     return d[0]
   a, b, *c = d
   if b in {'*', '/'}:
      vals = [a]
      while True:
         vals.append(c[0])
         if len(c) == 1 or c[1] != b:
            c = c[1:]
            break
         c = c[2:]
      return to_tree([{'op':b, 'vals':vals}, *c])
   return {'op':b, 'vals':[a, to_tree(c)]}
```

Now, creating a function to locate individual groups:

```
def traverse(d):
   if all(isinstance(i, str) for i in d['vals']):
      yield d
   for i in filter(lambda x:not isinstance(x, str), d['vals']):
      yield from traverse(i)

import re
exp = ['2*3=6', '3*2=6', '1+10/2=6.0', '2/1*3=6', '2*3/1=6', '3/1*2=6', '3*2/1=6', '10/2+1=6']
l = {a:list(traverse(to_tree(re.findall('\d+|[^\d]+', a.split('=')[0])))) for a in exp} 
def match(_exp, _l):
  return any(_l['op'] == i['op'] and len(_l['vals']) == len(i['vals']) and len(set(_l['vals'])&set(i['vals'])) == len(_l['vals']) for i in l[_exp])

result = [[i, [[j for j in b if match(i, j)] for a, b in l.items() if a != i]] for i in exp]
```

This method produces a list of lists that display operation blocks that are similar between the expression in question and all other expressions in the input list:

```
for a, b in result:
   print(a, list(filter(None, b)))
```

Output:

```
2*3=6 [[{'op': '*', 'vals': ['3', '2']}], [{'op': '*', 'vals': ['2', '3']}], [{'op': '*', 'vals': ['3', '2']}]]
3*2=6 [[{'op': '*', 'vals': ['2', '3']}], [{'op': '*', 'vals': ['2', '3']}], [{'op': '*', 'vals': ['3', '2']}]]
1+10/2=6.0 [[{'op': '/', 'vals': ['10', '2']}]]
2/1*3=6 []
2*3/1=6 [[{'op': '*', 'vals': ['2', '3']}], [{'op': '*', 'vals': ['3', '2']}], [{'op': '*', 'vals': ['3', '2']}]]
3/1*2=6 []
3*2/1=6 [[{'op': '*', 'vals': ['2', '3']}], [{'op': '*', 'vals': ['3', '2']}], [{'op': '*', 'vals': ['2', '3']}]]
10/2+1=6 [[{'op': '/', 'vals': ['10', '2']}]]
```

The goal of this solution is to provide not just single matching digits, but the actual child operational expressions.